# Amazon Elastic Map Reduce - Creating a job flow

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, elastic-map-reduce, emr

I'm very new to amazon services. I'm facing problems in creating job flows. Every time i create any job flow it fails or shuts down. Input, output or mapper function upload techniques are not clear to me. I have followed the developers section, but things are not getting clear. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

The error log is

```
Last State Change: No active keys found for user account
```

Comment: There could be a million reasons why an EMR jobflow fails, can you share your specific code that fails?

Answer (score 22):

This is the fix that worked for me and which you may need if your job flows are reporting the following error:

```
Last State Change: No active keys found for user account
```

When you create an AWS account, by default, the security access key has to be created for you. In some cases it will not be created automatically, so you should create one by yourself following these steps:

- Under the menu accessed by clicking your account name from within the AWS Console you will find a **Security Credentials** option. Click on it
- Expand the **Access Keys (Access Key ID and Secret Access Key)** section. Check if there is a key already created there.
- If no key found, then click on **Create new access key** and make it active (it should be set to active by default).
- Now create a job flow and it should work

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problems following the AWS tutorials creating my first AWS EMR Cluster.
The new AWS EMR console would try to create the cluster "Starting" but then after 2-4 mins the cluster status would change to "Terminated with errors : Validation error" and looking at the cluster details it said status "No active keys found for user account".

You must create an active access key in your security Credentials as advised above.
Then it worked fine for me.